# Zenity Shell Menu for 50+ servers, How to stay in server menu?

Tags: shell-script, ssh, zenity

i am trying to make a zenity shell menu to manage 50+ servers and want to add multiple customized functions. e.g:- when server goes down i want to ssh in it, then check load,free -m, last 10 mins apache/nginx logs,exim logs,mysql slow query logs and many more. i have scripts for all these needs.

those servers have my ssh key so theres no problm in doing ssh.

i am successfully logging in servers, but the thing is when i get into server via ssh, the script ends and after i exit for server, i comes on my local machine's terminal with no script, then i have to again run script to get server menu.
Please tell me how can i stay in loop i mean how to stay in server menu , then ssh into any server, and when i exit from server come back to server menu. 
 please help . i want to customize it more.

=========== its short script to give you guys idea. my origial script have all servers======

```
#!/bin/bash
dialog --menu "select" 40 40 5 1 server.hades 2 server.fire 3 server.geb 4 server.isis 5 exit 2> /tmp/a
choice=`cat /tmp/a`
if [ $choice -eq 1 ]
then
ssh 1.2.3.4
fi
if [ $choice -eq 2 ]
then
ssh 2.3.4.5
fi
if [ $choice -eq 3 ]
then
ssh 2.3.3.5
fi
if [ $choice -eq 4 ]
then
ssh 8.3.4.8
fi
if [ $choice -eq 5 ]
then
echo "BIE BIE"
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to run the script in some loop, but you miss the loop. The simples modification will probably be this modification:

```
[... the rest of choices ...]
if [ $choice -eq 5 ]
then
  echo "BYE BYE"
  exit
fi
exec $0
```

This will exit if you will choose the last option (5), but otherwise reexecute the script itself.

Or just add a cycle:

```
while true;
do
  dialog --menu "select" 40 40 5 1 server.hades 2 server.fire 3 server.geb 4 server.isis 5 exit 2> /tmp/a
  choice=`cat /tmp/a`
  if [ $choice -eq 2 ]
  then
    ssh 192.168.187.*
  fi
  [... the rest of choices ...]
  if [ $choice -eq 5 ]
  then
    echo "BIE BIE"
    break
  fi
done
```

"while" code worked for me. thankyou.

Comment: it didnt work, ended up with error. Please help.
[root@server ~]# sh sshautologin
### now menu comes ####



Last login: Tue May  9 01:25:13 2017 from 192.168.187.129
[root@server ~]# 
[root@server ~]# 
[root@server ~]# ip a | grep -w inet
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet 192.168.187.139/24 brd 192.168.187.255 scope global dynamic eno16777736
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
[root@server ~]# exit
logout
Connection to 192.168.187.139 closed.
sshautologin: line 13: exec: sshautologin: not found
[root@centeralized Desktop]#

Comment: How do you start the script?

Comment: `sh script`
on exiting from remote server its again logging in server via ssh, i think it is because of i am saving the dialog choice in file. please tell me how to get back to menu

Comment: `while true;
do
dialog --menu "select" 40 40 5 1 server.hades 2 server.fire 3 server.geb 4 server.isis 5 exit 2> /tmp/a
choice=`cat /tmp/a`
if [ $choice -eq 2 ]
then
ssh *.*.*.*
fi
if [ $choice -eq 5 ]
then
echo "BIE BIE"
break
fi
done`
its working with "while".
thankyou